# Пустой массив с длиной 4 преобразовывая в строку, добавил элемент, который должен был повторяться. Почему на (length -1)?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.write(new Array(4).join("космос"));
```

Но получается 3 "космоса". Я же создал пустой массив с длиной 4.
Дело в позиции элементов, которые начинаются с нуля?

Comment: `join` соеденяет элементы массива с помощью переданой в него строки, 4 элемента = 3 пустых места между ними

Comment: Получается, "космос" не элемент, выступал в роли разделителя, как если бы, например, поставил бы запятую!?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: Понял, благодарю!

Answer (score 4):

Как было сказано в комментариях - метод `join()` объединяет все элементы массива в строку. Получилось, что вы создали массив из 4 пустых элементов, и хотите объединить эти элементы в строку разделив их словом "космос". Вот и получается что их 3. У вас получается вот такая строка:

```
el[0] + 'космос' + el[1] + 'космос' + el[2] + 'космос' + el[3]
```

Обычно к этому методу прибегают, чтобы список элементов соединенных в строку был читаемым, например:

```js
var elements = ['один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре'];
console.log(elements.join());
console.log(elements.join(''));
console.log(elements.join(' -> '));
```

Comment: +++++++++++++++

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan Лучше примите ответ, плюсы не о чем не говорят. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: В смысле,  ответить, что понятно?

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нажмите слева вверху от ответа на галочку, для "+" стрелка вверх, для "-" стрелка вниз